# Error in is.url(url) : length(url) == 1 when status code = 404

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function that will query the said mentioned API (baseurl) based on input: test_doi. The code works fine if the url returned 200, but once the url returned 404, i received the following error message.

Error in is.url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE

My code:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

call_dim <- function(x) {
  baseurl <- "https://metrics-api.dimensions.ai/doi/"
  url <- paste0(baseurl, x)
  resp <- GET(url)
  if(status_code(resp) == 404){
    stop("NA", call. = FALSE)
  } else {
    pages_t <- fromJSON(paste0(baseurl,x))
    lapply(pages_t, function(z) { z[ lengths(z) == 0 ] <- NA; z; })
  } 
 }


test_doi <- c("10.3390/w10111643" ,"10.1371/journal.pone.0007108")
view <- call_dim(test_doi)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your function was written to fetch one url at a time. You need to account for that by using one of the apply family functions. In your case, I modified your function to return the content of the request so that it's easier to debug what is going on and use `sapply`.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

call_dim <- function(x) {
  baseurl <- "https://metrics-api.dimensions.ai/doi/"
  url <- paste0(baseurl, x)
  resp <- GET(url)
  if(status_code(resp) == 404){
    return(content(resp))
  } else {
    pages_t <- fromJSON(paste0(baseurl,x))
    lapply(pages_t, function(z) { z[ lengths(z) == 0 ] <- NA; z; })
  } 
}


test_doi <- c("10.3390/w10111643" ,"10.1371/journal.pone.0007108")
view <- sapply(test_doi, call_dim)

> str(view)
List of 2
 $ 10.3390/w10111643           : chr "404: Not Found"
 $ 10.1371/journal.pone.0007108:List of 9
  ..$ doi                    : chr "10.1371/journal.pone.0007108"
  ..$ times_cited            : int 17
  ..$ recent_citations       : int 1
  ..$ highly_cited_1         : logi FALSE
  ..$ highly_cited_5         : logi FALSE
  ..$ highly_cited_10        : logi FALSE
  ..$ relative_citation_ratio: num 0.63
  ..$ field_citation_ratio   : num 2.39
  ..$ license                : chr "This data has been sourced via the Dimensions Metrics API, use of which is subject to the terms at https://dime"| __truncated__
```